# Query table names

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc

I have been given access to a database. I am querying the data from a spark cluster. How do I check all the databases/tables I have access to?

```
jdbcUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://{0}:{1};database={2};user='{3}';password='{4}'".format(jdbcHostname, jdbcPort, jdbcDatabase, jdbcUsername, jdbcPassword)
connectionProperties = {
  "user" : jdbcUsername,
  "password" : jdbcPassword, 
  "driver" : "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
}
df = spark.read.jdbc(url=jdbcUrl, properties=connectionProperties)
```

Access to the database has been authenticated.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server itself:

```
select *
  from sys.tables
```

Not sure if you use synonym or not as the way into the sys schema.

```
val tables = spark.read.jdbc(jdbc_url, "sys.tables", connectionProperties)
tables.select(...
```

If you have synonym, replace the sys.tables with that. There are different ways of writing, you go down the tables or own SQL Query approach approach. This is the tables approach. Here under the SQL Query approach, an example:

```
val dataframe_mysql = spark.read.jdbc(jdbcUrl, "(select k, v from sample order by k DESC) e", connectionProperties)
```

SCALA version I just realized.

**pyspark specifically**

See: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

Just the same approach, but specifically for this case postgres:

```
jdbcDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver") \
    .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename") \
    .option("user", "username") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .load()
```

JDBC loading and saving can be achieved via either the load/save or jdbc methods, see the guide.